# Suppose you have socks loose in a drawer. You have a black sock, a gray sock and a tan sock. How many outcomes are there for selecting 2 socks?

Tags: probability

b.How many ways can you select 2 socks without replacement?

c.How many ways can you get a black and a tan sock?

I was thinking For the first question and part b,the answer is there's 1/3.And for part C since there's one sock color of black and tan,then it's 2/3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\binom{3}{2}=3$ ways of selecting two socks without replacement (assuming that choosing black then tan is equivalent to choosing tan then black etc.). There is only one way of choosing a black and tan sock, i.e. the probability of picking a black and tan sock is 1/3.